# onTouch в GridView

Tags: android

Необходимо после обработки долгого нажатия переместить картинку.
Нажимаем на картинку , начинаем перемещать и в логах видно что нет обработки нажатия ACTION_DOWN  , а происходит ACTION_MOVE и за ним сразу ACTION_CANCEL.
Если отпустить картинку и нажать снова обработки долгого нажатия нет, она сразу начинает перемещаться и в логах происходит ACTION_DOWN и за ним ACTION_CANCEL. Причем ACTION_CANCEL в обоих случаях срабатывает до того как отпустили картинку.
Ребят помогите разобраться.

адаптер гридВью, обработка нажатия

```
 imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLongClick");

            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item("" + position); 
                    String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_HTML}; 
                    ClipData data = new ClipData("" + position, mimeTypes, item);  
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v); 
                    v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//n

                    Log.i(TAG, "onTouch");
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            sDown = "Down: " + x + "," + y;
                            sMove = "";
                            sUp = "";
                            Log.i(TAG, "DOWN" + sDown + sMove);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            sMove = "Move: " + x + "," + y;
                            Log.i(TAG, "move" + sMove);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            Log.i(TAG, "up");
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            sMove = "";
                            sUp = "Up: " + x + "," + y;
                            Log.i(TAG, "cancel(up)" + sUp + sMove);
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

нажали на картинку и переместили
[image: нажили на картинку]
нажали второй раз и переместили
[image: нажали второй раз]

Comment: action_cancel, возможно, происходит, когда вы перетягиваете View за границу текущего элемента списка. Вы можете использовать одно из десятка уже готовых решений, если вам нужно менять местами элементы в GridView при помощи Drag-and-Drop, например это https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid

Comment: @metalurgus   спасибо за совет, но не могу заставить работать   BaseDynamicGridAdapter с картинками, и пример нигде не нашел. Наведите на путь истинный ))